# Non English text in Android DialogFragment shows as question marks

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I've encountered a problem while trying to create a DialogFragment which includes a title and some text in `hebrew`.

the text shows as `??? ??? ??` , while the English text appears to be in order.

My code :

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.info_fragment, null);
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(textEntryView)
                .setTitle(<some sentence in hebrew>)
                .setMessage(<another hebrew text>)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                }).create();
}
```

p.s.
If I create a regular AlertDialog within my activity, hebrew text shows just fine.
Can it appear like so using a fragment with an AlertDialog inside it?

any idea how to solve this?
thank you!!

Image of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhrlL.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create folder `values-he` inside `res` folder and copy `strings.xml` file here from `res ⇒ values ⇒ strings.xml` location.

Go to `res ⇒ values ⇒ strings.xml` then declare string:

```
<string name="hebrew_title">hello</string>
```

Go to `res ⇒ values-he ⇒ strings.xml` then declare string:

```
<string name="hebrew_title">שלום</string>
```

Then in your code write like this:

```
.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.hebrew_title))
```

So when you set the device local language to `hebrew`. Your text will be shown in 'hebrew' language. Hope this will solve your problem.

Note: Be also sure that the strings have the same `id` in both `strings.xml` files of `values-he` and `values` folder.

Comment: What is the difference between them? Why you think this way will work?

Comment: It makes the text in English if the device is not localized to hebrew.
 my device is in english and has hebrew as a second language. If I create a regular AlertDialog within my activity, hebrew text shows just fine. can it appear like so using a fragment with an AlertDialog inside it?

Comment: I think you are using `windows-1252 Encoding` in your Android Studio that's why you are getting `????` in Android Emulator. Change Encoding to `utf-8`. You will not get `???`